# Problem with Boost bidirectionnal iterator not writable

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, boost-iterators

I try to make bidirectionnal iterators with Boost Iterator. I have implemented some functions as suggested in the documentation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html).

I have a parent class where the functions to implement are declared pure virtual (I need polymorphic iterators). For the moment, I have one inherited class where the functions are implemented. Moreover, I use boost::bidirectional_traversal_tag.

The dereference() function is implemented as follows in the inherited class:

```
template <typename T>
T& ImageIterator_NotPlanar<T>::dereference() const {
  return *((T*)buffer);
}
```

to read values as the following example, it works perfectly:

```
for (; !iter.isEndReached(); ++iter)
  cout << "ITERATOR INC: " << *iter << endl;
```

(where isEndReached() is a personal function). The problem is that the following code doesn't works:

```
*iter = 3;
```

g++ returns the following error:

```
lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

What is wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: The error probably means that you passed the incorrect `Value` or `Reference` template when deriving from `iterator_facade`. It's a shame you didn't just post your full iterator definition, as the error would have probably been obvious.

Answer (score 0):

We need to see *exactly* where the error is generated. Also, we have to assume you have the proper non-const version

Could it be you need to have

```
template <typename T>
T& ImageIterator_NotPlanar<T>::dereference() {
  return *((T*)buffer);
}

template <typename T>
T const& ImageIterator_NotPlanar<T>::dereference() const {
  return *((T*)buffer);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried to delete the const after dereference() as your first proposition, but I have the error "no matching function for call to... dereference() const". I don't understand how to make a writable iterator with Boost Iterator, and honestly, I think the documentation is incomprehensible on the subject. For the error, it comes from the line where there is `*iter = 3`, I have no more informations from the compiler. Thanks

Comment: Did you create _both_ overloads as shown? Also, a minimal working sample and compiler message _WITH_ line numbers is something you should be able to provide. Compilers report line numbers.

Comment: Yes, I created overloads, but I think they are not overloads since boost doesn't call such functions. For the compiler, the only error I have is `/home/benlaug/projets/tfe/tfe_seg_perfs/test/main_test.cc:79:11: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment` and main_test.cc:79 is `*iter = 3;`. I really don't understand how to make writable iterators.

Comment: Two functions with the same name in the same scope are _by definition_ overloads. I understand that you _meant to say_ they are not being called (quite likely boost will want you to specialize a dereference 'policy' to avoid the cost of virtuals). Just post a working sample and we'll spot the problem in seconds. I promise. There is heaps of c++ knowledge here on SO. This isn't working for lack of clarity in the question

Comment: The problem is that the code is a little bit long. Is a link to a site as pastebin is OK? I found a new element in the iterator_facade documentation. In the section iterator_facade operations, there is `reference operator*() const;`. Apparently, there is no way to make a writable bidirectionnal iterator. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Whatever works! I prefer it if you slimmed it down, though; most often you'll find the problem just by isolating it :)

Comment: @benlaug let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1064/discussion-between-sehe-and-benlaug)

Comment: I was basically saying : post whatever way you can; i prefer if you can slim it down, of course; at a minimum it should portray the problem you refer to (preferrably, only that :))

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help. But I gave up Boost. I wrote personal iterators with nothing from the STL and Boost and it works perfectly. Time of the operation: 15 minutes. Time lost with Boost iterators: 2 days.

Comment: Cheers. I've done the same in the past. I do hope you'll not come to see that the cost down the road is the same. Then again, if you don't need heavy duty generic purpose library-grade iterators, well... I sort of agree you can probably live without Boost Iterator